# set up vscode for python on MacOS Monterrey

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

im new to programming, I was able to set up .ipynb to work properly but I have issues when I try to run a program in .py any pointers? [python 3.10.6 - MacOS 12.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyek.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `python` command points to the pre-installed `python2` version by default in MAC. But since *Monterey 12.3*, the system is not pre-installed with `python2`, so the `"zsh: command not found: python"` error occurs.

The solution is to point `python` to `python3` using the following command.

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: I fixed the issue by simply installing Xcode command line tools and typing python3 in the terminal.